Name for relation between trees being isomorphic after collapsing a single subtree
Suppose I have two rooted trees $T_1$ and $T_2$, such that if I select a subtree in $T_1$ and collapse it into single node (i.e. delete all nodes under the root of this subtree), then I end up with $T_2$. Is there a name for and/or much study of this relation?
If it makes any difference, the context I have in mind is binary trees in the parsing of natural language, so children are labelled either 'right' or 'left'.

Please clarify the collapse operation: how do the labels/values in that subtree merge to a single value? Does it mean simply deleting all nodes under it? In that case, your problem is simply deciding whether $T_2$ is a subgraph of $T_1$.

@codeR subgraphs might involve more than one collapses

Yes, it means deleting all nodes under the root of the subtree, I'll clarify. Subgraph is too general because we can't delete the root, and also, and EnEm points out, because we can only collapse only one subtree,

Rather than asking for a name of a relation, it's usually better to ask what you want to know.  That way, even if there is no "name" for it, you still have learned something.  The great thing about language is that we can describe many more concepts than there are names for.  Asking for a "study" of this relation is too vague.  This site is for focused, answerable technical questions.

Are you just talking about the structure of the trees, or will your leaves be labeled with some character and you want all the leaf node labels to match up with each other? And if so, since you mention left and right children, you need these labels to be placed exactly in the same left/right positions in both trees?

This relation is coming up in sth I'm researching on parsing natural language. Depending on where I take this research, there are different questions I might like to answer: how many trees, up to isomorphism, bear this relation to a given tree? some sort of probability of two trees bearing this relation, how this changes with $n$ etc. For now, it would be helpful to know a term to search to see if there is existing literature on it, or else if it hasn't been looked at much before, that would also be helpful to know.

Subtree isomorphism is a large area, and it seems you want a restricted form of the rooted version, but you may or may not want the ordered version.

Thanks, from looking up 'rooted subtee isomorphism', I am not sure if it enforces that only one subtree can be collapsed.
